What is the distribution of a ratio of two normal distributions?
Assume that I have a resistor with an unknown resistance R. I measure the current trough it, I, and the voltage across it, U.
I can then estimate R:
$$
\hat{R} = \frac{U}{I}
$$
Let us assume I get the following result:
$$
\hat{R} = \frac{5V}{100mA} = 50 \Omega
$$
But how certain is this estimate?
Let us assume that the uncertainty in U is: $U \pm \delta U$ where $\delta U = 1mV$ and that the uncertainty in I is: $I \pm \delta I$ where $\delta I = 1mA$.
One way I could perhaps analyze this is by assuming that the measurements are normally distributed:
$$
U \sim N(\mu_U,\sigma_U^2)
$$
$$
I \sim N(\mu_I,\sigma_I^2)
$$
where $2\sigma_U = \delta U = 1mV$ and $2\sigma_I = \delta I = 1mA$.
If I then could find the distribution of R I could assume that R would be within the 95 % percentile around the average value $\hat{R}=\mu_U/\mu_I$.
But what is the distribution of R?
Does an analytical expression for this exist?
Or should I perform a Monte Carlo simulation where I draw say 1000 $U_i$ and $I_i$ values, compute $R_i = U_i/I_i$ and inspect the histogram for $\{R_i\}_{i=1}^{1000}$?

Your question is a reasonable exercise in probability theory, but I do question if it makes sense for physics. Normal distributions can be negative. Can current and impedence?

@Dave: current and voltage can be negative, but resistance can not be negative. Therefore if the current is negative so is the voltage.  Assuming that U and I are >> 0 does this matter? Say U = 5 V +- 1mV. Yes for a normal distribution U could be < 0 but the percentile for this would be very small.

It's worth stressing that if this is a problem you're really trying to solve, and not an academic exercise, the Monte Carlo approach is very quick and simple to run, and should always be preferred to any analytic approximation.

@Eoin "Always preferred" is so absolute as to be worth questioning.  Some approximations can be so good that it would take astronomical amounts of time for any Monte Carlo method to approach them in accuracy.  Simulation, although always advisable for checking gross errors and establishing intuition, is not a panacea.
